# How to execute "Blow to the hart" mission in Star Conflict?

Tags: star-conflict

How to execute "Blow to the hart" mission in Star Conflict?

Mission states:

> I should attack the enemy captain in Combat Recon or defend your own

I don't understand what that means.

Should I get "Combat Recon" type of ship? if so - how?

Or defend own... - is that type of battle?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete this quest you have to play PVP missions, during these missions one of the game modes is Combat Recon, each side has a captain assigned to it randomly, and the goal is to kill the enemy captain to win.

To complete it play the mission type "Combat Recon" and it should complete.

Comment: Yeah,... recently get level 4 so this mission was unlocked so now I understand what quest is about. Is there any way I can choose the mission type or it is always random?